# Makefile with error - No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, macos, makefile

I've got simple `makefile` in my Ruby app which should zip code to `temp` directory.

`makefile`

```
pack:
    rm -f temp/devops_bot* && pushd source && zip -r -q ../temp/devops_bot.zip * && popd

terraform:
    terraform apply
```

however I've got an error `No such file or directory`

`console`

```
✗ make pack
rm -f temp/devops_bot* && pushd source && zip -r -q ../temp/devops_bot.zip * && popd
/bin/sh: line 0: pushd: source: No such file or directory
make: *** [pack] Error 1
```

Comment: This sounds  like a bash issue -- if you cut and paste theline `rm -f temp/devops_bot* && pushd source && zip -r -q ../temp/devops_bot.zip * && popd`, and run it on the bash shell ( from the directory you invoked make from), do you get the same error?...   Check if there's a directory named `source` in there.

Comment: It does sound like a shell issue not a make issue, but just to note: `pushd` and `popd` are best used interactively; they're much less useful in scripting where it's much simpler to simply use a subshell, like: `rm -f temp/devops_bot* && (cd source && zip -r -q ../temp/devops_bot.zip *)`.  By putting the cd in a subshell (in parens) it will be undone automatically (like all environment changes) when the subshell exits.  Also this is portable, whereas `pushd` and `popd` are not standard and don't exist in all `/bin/sh` implementations.